# I have struggling to understand the following

Tags: angularjs, json, scope

I used $http request to get the json data like this

```js
$http.get('test.json')
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.contents=response;
        });
```

but when i inspected in developers tool in chrome,
it showing

```js
$http.get('test.json')
        .success(function(response) { response=Array[84]// here i got json array
            $scope.contents=response;  // here Also response=array[84]
        });
```

but $scope.contents is undefined when i put breakpoint to check the value of $scope.contents.
Why is it happening?
Am i Doing anything wrong here?``

Comment: First define $scope.contents in your controller.

Comment: Where do you put that breakpoint? When are you evaluating it? Are you sure it's the same $scope? Post a complete example reproducing the problem. Oh, and stop using success(): it's deprecated.

Comment: Add the example where you put breakpoint, you can't use `response` outside the `$http.get`

Comment: try console.log(response); console.log($scope.contents); instead of setting a break point. and check in developer console.

Comment: @JB nizet, yes it is same $scope. i put break-point at $http.get()

Comment: So, if you put the breakpoint there, the HTTP request has not been sent yet, the response has not come back yet, the success callback function has not been executed yet, and $scope.contents is thus not defined yet. That's quite normal.

Answer (score -1):

you have to make change as follows:

```
$http.get('test.json')
        .success(function(response) { response=Array[84]// here i got json array
            $scope.contents=response.data;  // here Also response=array[84]
        });
```

now it will give correct result when check for $scope.contents.

Comment: That's incorrect. The success function receives the response data as its first argument. And the OP has the right data, as he's saying in his question.

Comment: After putting console.log($scope.contents);

Comment: console bar displaying like this... 
0: {lon: "77.5558", phone: "07204897790", cityId: 1, location: "Madventures'", categoryId: 1,…}........ so on

is it means $scope.contents contains array of json object?

Comment: ok thanks..  Is it possible to store only  phone attribute from this array into database?

Comment: yes , you can. just pass the phone attribute as a param for your $http.post method

Comment: How exactly??.. Any syntax??

Comment: $http.post('REST URL',{params: {parameterName: parameterValue}})

Comment: $http.post('REST URL',{params{phone:$scope.contents[objectIndex].phone}})

Comment: I got it... thanks... is it possible to do like this $scope.phonenumber= 
$http.post('REST URL',{params{phone:$scope.contents[objectIndex].phone}})    so that the returned result of phone is stored in $scope.phonenumber..

Comment: if i want to store the phone attribute in $scope.phonenumber is it necessary to use $http.post() method?...

Comment: yes you can but you have return the value. there can be other way to do that also. Instead of assigning value from post call assign it directly to $scope.phoneNumber and just put one check if your database insertion gets failed then do not assign value to $scope.phoneNumber. because the chances of second condition are very less.and you need to return value each time for your post call.

Comment: $scope.phonenumber=$scope.contents[1].phone;   will it store in $scope.phonenumber

Comment: After using $scope.phonenumber=$scope.contents[1].phone; it saying that TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined..

Comment: It is happening because your $scope.contents is undefined; Please in init() method define $scope.contents=[]; and then call your $http.get method. Then you will be having data in $scope.contents

Comment: $scope.eventid=$scope.contents[0].eventID; this should be inside $http.get() method or inside controller?

Comment: If you want to assign values after your get call then assign it in  .success method .

Comment: sorry.... Type error:cant read property of 1 undefined that error is solved.    now  after doing
$scope.phonenumber=$scope.contents[1].phone;   it saying $scope.phonenumber is undefined;